# How to read default string

Tags: java, string

I have a file with String in a certain format, I like to capture this string some information. example:

```
0:13:13 - ID:( id ) / Name:( name ) / IP ( 177.22.XX.X ) Memory Function Code Error ( 1 )( 267 354 24 )( 12 15 5 )
```

I would take the data as time, id, name, ip and the description of sentence.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: please show what you have already found?

Comment: Simple `string.Split()` calls ought to do it, if the format is consistent.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your example:

```
String input = "0:13:13 - ID:( id ) / Name:( name ) / IP ( 177.22.3.4) Memory Function Code Error ( 1 )( 267 354 24 )( 12 15 5 )";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([\\d\\:]+).*ID:.*\\((.+)\\).*Name:\\((.+?)\\).*?IP \\((.+?)\\)(.+)").matcher(input);
while(m.find()){
    String date = m.group(1).trim();
    String id = m.group(2).trim();
    String name = m.group(3).trim();
    String ip = m.group(4).trim();
    String desc = m.group(5).trim();

    System.out.println("Date: " + date);
    System.out.println("ID: " + id);
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("IP: " + ip);
    System.out.println("Desc: " + desc);
}
```

Prints:

```
Date: 0:13:13
ID: id
Name: name
IP: 177.22.3.4
Desc: Memory Function Code Error ( 1 )( 267 354 24 )( 12 15 5 )
```